# When i run the code, all my checkboxes get selected.How do i make this stop?

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

I made a cancel button which removes the boxes I check manually, after I made it I set the command to be the function which you can see in my code. The cancel button works but after I implemented it for some reason all my boxes get checked automatically when I run the code.

````py
Cancel1=tkinter.StringVar()
Cancel2=tkinter.StringVar()
Cancel3=tkinter.StringVar()
Cancel4=tkinter.StringVar()
Cancel5=tkinter.StringVar()
Cancel6=tkinter.StringVar()
Cancel7=tkinter.StringVar()
Cancel8=tkinter.StringVar()


def cancel() :
    Cancel1.set(0)
    Cancel2.set(0)
    Cancel3.set(0)
    Cancel4.set(0)
    Cancel5.set(0)
    Cancel6.set(0)
    Cancel7.set(0)
    Cancel8.set(0)


window.title("Menu")

c1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window,text="Pizza("+str(cijenaPizza)+ ")",onvalue=1,offvalue=0,variable=Cancel1)
c1.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)```
````

Comment: btw usually for Checkbutton `IntVar()` is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here. You can either use `IntVar()` as the `variable` (by default it is set to `0` which is your `offvalue` too):

```
import tkinter as tk
   

c1 = tk.Checkbutton(
    window,text="Pizza("+str(cijenaPizza)+ ")",
    onvalue=1,
    offvalue=0,
    variable=tk.IntVar()
)
```

or make sure to set `Cancel1` to the `offvalue`:

```
import tkinter as tk
   
Cancel1=tk.StringVar()
Cancel1.set('0')

c1 = tk.Checkbutton(
    window,text="Pizza("+str(cijenaPizza)+ ")",
    onvalue=1,
    offvalue=0,
    variable=Cancel1
)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot sir for being so helpful, it works perfectly with both options!